# codeigniter file upload returning array of 1?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Would like to seek for help on CodeIgniter file upload class return data. I upload a file around 2mb and CodeIgniter did upload the file for me, but returned an array one '1', instead of the details. Any idea?

I have checked the php.ini **post_max_size** and **upload_max_filesize**, they are 8M and 10M. So I suppose it should be no problem.

Comment: Solved: It was due to memory_limit. I increased the value, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the wrong object, print the $this->upload object and not the do-upload function which in your case is returning 1 meaning true